# VBA set a value for a Global variant to call in others publics

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, global-variables, rgb

In my access I have 10 buttons which I have to change this colors according to some events.
I want to not declare a RGB in all buttons

that is how I do:

```
Global greencolor As Variant

Public Function mp01()
greencolor = RGB(119, 221, 119)

Form_Frm_Processing.mp_02.BackColor = greencolor

End Function

Public Function mp02()
greencolor = RGB(119, 221, 119)

Form_Frm_Processing.mp_02.BackColor = greencolor

End Function
```

'-------------------------------------------------

that is how I want:

```
Global greencolor As Variant
greencolor = RGB(119, 221, 119)

Public Function mp01()

Form_Frm_Processing.mp_02.BackColor = greencolor

End Function

Public Function mp02()

Form_Frm_Processing.mp_02.BackColor = greencolor

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `Const`:

`Public Const greencolor As Long = 7855479`

If you need to use a function, you can use a predeclared object. See [this example](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/18932/vb-predeclaredid). Note it will run the function each time the value is retrieved. That can be avoided by setting the values when initializing the object

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```vb
Public Const greencolor As Long = 7855479  ' RGB(119, 221, 119)


Public Function mp01()

    Form_Frm_Processing.mp_02.BackColor = greencolor

End Function


Public Function mp02()

    Form_Frm_Processing.mp_02.BackColor = greencolor

End Function
```

Comment: this way return a error:
Compile error: Expected: end of statement

Comment: Yes, `Const` was missing, sorry.